# ServiceStack - DateTime SerializeFn from Cache different from Database

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

In my Servicestack application, I'm trying to serialize the Datetime from database into RFC3339 standard. 
The datetime stored in the databases is local time. For my application, the database is located in 2 different location, one is Indonesia with +7 offset, another is Malaysia with +8 offset. Both database stored with the local time respectively.

Same application is used to serve both database from different location. The local time for the application is with **offset +8**, is located in Malaysia.

When the datetime is from Indonesia database, for example **"2014-09-19 14:07:27.387"**(2pm), i will append the offset +7 into **"2014-09-19T14:07:27.3870000+07:00"**(2pm+7). The following is the code for SerializeFn

```
JsConfig<DateTime?>.SerializeFn = time =>
        {
            if (time != null)
            {
                DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = DateTimeZone.GetDateTimeOffset((DateTime)time, CommonFunction.GetDbCountryCode());
                return string.Format("{0:O}", dateTimeOffset);
            }
            return null;
        };
```

The codes for the GetDateTimeOffset function:

```
    public static DateTimeOffset GetDateTimeOffset(DateTime dateTime, string country)
    {
        switch (country.ToUpper())
        {
            case "ID":
                return new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, TimeSpan.FromHours(+7));
            default:
                return new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, TimeSpan.FromHours(+8)); ;
        }
    }
```

Then the Redis cached the value as **"2014-09-19T14:07:27.3870000+07:00"**(2pm+7). The subsequent request will get from the Redis cached value and .NET application will auto convert into application local time which turn into **"2014-09-19 15:07:27.387"**(3pm, Application local time is offset +8) before the SerializeFn.

The datetime's hours has increased by 1 hour. The output value from the cache that go through the same SerializeFn has become **"2014-09-19T15:07:27.3870000+07:00"**(3pm+7)

The datetime from cache for Indonesia +7 has increased by hours due to the auto conversion in .NET.

Is it anyway to identify where is the sources from in the SerializeFn? Can anyone guide me if I'm doing in the correct way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution. Added DeserializeFn to process the data from cache. And previously there are some part missed out to change in the code caused the solution didn't work.

```
        DateTimeOffset dto = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<DateTimeOffset>(time);
        DateTime temp = new DateTime(dto.UtcDateTime.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return DateTimeZone.ConvertDateTimeZoneFromUTC(CommonFunction.GetDbCountryCode(), temp);
```